# RegEx match uppercase letter not after dash

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match uppercase letters only in the second string

```
dashed-String-With-Uppercase
camesCaseString
```

I've tried this one `(?<!-)([A-Z])`, but negative lookbehind doesn't work in javascript. Can it be solved another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a negated character class with an alternation checking the beginning of the string:

```
(^|[^-])([A-Z])
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zN0wE9/4)

Then, you can restore the part before the uppercase letter with the `$1` back-reference.

Here is a demo showing how to insert hyphens before uppercase letters that are not alreaydy preceded with a hyphen:

```js
var re = /(^|[^-])([A-Z])/g; 
var str = 'dashed-String-With-Uppercase\ncamesCaseString';
var result = str.replace(re, "$1-$2");
document.write(result.replace(/\n/g, "<br/>"));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
[^-]([A-Z])
```

You can use this and grab the group.